# Sumoselect plugin not working with dynamically select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sumoselect.js

I am using sumoselect plugin (http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html).

I have two select dropdowns. First, one I directly added to the HTML page and the second one I am displaying dynamically using jQuery.

sumoselect plugin is working only for the first one select dropdown but not working with the second one.

Would you help me out with this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fileStatus').SumoSelect();
  var wrapper = $(".appentInside .row"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".click_me"); //Add button ID
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click

    $(wrapper).append('<select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected="">Select</option><option value="1"> One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3"> Three</option></select>');
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/sumoselect.min.css">

<select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="fileStatus">
  <option disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
  <option value="1"> One</option>
  <option value="2"> Two</option>
  <option value="3"> Three</option>
</select>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="click_me">click me to display seocnd dropdown</a>
<div class="appentInside">
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/jquery.sumoselect.min.js"></script>
```

After using @Terry answer

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fileStatus').SumoSelect();

  $('.fileStatus:first').change(function() {
    var fileStatus = $('.fileStatus option:selected').val();
    $('.fileStatus:last').val(fileStatus);
  })

  var wrapper = $(".appentInside .row"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".click_me"); //Add button ID
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    var fileStatus = $('.fileStatus:last option:selected').val();
    $(wrapper).append('<select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected="">Select</option><option value="1"> One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3"> Three</option></select>').find('.fileStatus').SumoSelect();
    $('.fileStatus:last').val(fileStatus);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your new `.fileStatus` dropdown is added **after runtime**, and the code `$('.fileStatus').SumoSelect()` has already been invoked. It is important to remember that JS is not reactive in the sense that it will automatically find new elements all the time: you will need to instantiate SumoSelect on the new `<select>` element that is added.

You can simply do this by chaining `.find('.fileStatus').SumoSelect()` after the `.append()` method, because by then the new `.fileStatus` element will be already present in the DOM:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fileStatus').SumoSelect();
  var wrapper = $(".appentInside .row"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".click_me"); //Add button ID
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click

    $(wrapper).append('<select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected="">Select</option><option value="1"> One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3"> Three</option></select>').find('.fileStatus').SumoSelect();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/sumoselect.min.css">

<select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="fileStatus">
  <option disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
  <option value="1"> One</option>
  <option value="2"> Two</option>
  <option value="3"> Three</option>
</select>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="click_me">click me to display seocnd dropdown</a>
<div class="appentInside">
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/jquery.sumoselect.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give me some time to understand your answer.

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly for me. I just want know how do I use .find('.fileStatus').SumoSelect(); with separate variable. I mean I don't want to use with append. Can I use like var x=find('.fileStatus').SumoSelect();

Comment: I added on the script in the question, after using your answer my script is not working. If I choose anything from the dropdown and click on the link then it will display the select dropdown with the auto select field. and if you change the option value then it will change the select value. for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768333/the-first-dropdown-selected-and-displays-the-same-selected-option-value-on-the-s